# How to create a liquid meniscus/bridge between two surfaces

Tags: modeling, physics, fluid-simulation, meta-objects

I'm trying to model a water droplet between two plane surfaces such that it forms a capillary bridge as soon as the surfaces get into close proximity of each other like in the first figure of this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_bridges

I tried to play with the fluid simulation but I can only get an "infinite" stream of water. I also tried metaballs but I was only able to "melt" two balls with each other.

How would you do this?

Comment: Do you need it to be fluid simulation, or modeling and animating it can be a solution?

Comment: it doesn't need to be a fluid simulation, I just want it to look more or less realistic :)

Comment: Is it a still or an animation?

Comment: It would be cool if I could animate it. The idea is to have a sessile or a hanging drop on one of the surfaces and then when they approach each other the capillary bridge forms and when they move away from each other the bridge breaks again.

Comment: Like in this video : https://youtu.be/3fJl2jAsoMk?t=14